# xattr issue Sierra

Tags: terminal, macos, vmware

I was trying to remove extended attributes (quarantine) in order to install Fusion. This is what I ran in terminal:

```
sudo xattr -rc /Volumes/VMware\ Fusion/VMware\ Fusion.app
```

Apparently, the instruction was applied to `/Volumes` instead of just the app. In consequence, lots of troubles appeared after a restart:

- characters are not being displayed (only question marks inside a box)
- permissions or ownership of lots of folders and files were messed up
- chaos

I would like to know why this happened and if there's any way to revert it back to default. I tried to run `RepairHomePermissions` from recovery mode as describe here: [macOS Sierra Recovery HD Changes](https://sneakypockets.wordpress.com/2016/09/21/macos-sierra-recovery-hd-changes) but it didn't help. With a different system user everything works fine so I don't know if only the home folder was affected.

Comment: To remove the quarantine attribute, it's better to use `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine` and leave other extended attributes in place.

Answer (score 1):

If you really entered the command as shown, the change should be local to `VMware Fusion.app`. But anyway, if you want to restore things back to sanity, you can

- redownload and reinstall macOS Sierra from the Store
- boot into the Recovery Partition and reinstall from there

Comment: That's what I will do but I was mainly looking for an explanation. Is xattr capable of that kind of destruction? It changed the ownership of home folders from user:staff to root:wheel

Comment: No, it isn't. If you are looking at permission issues, `xattr` isn't the culprit.